# Bootstrap selectpicker library not working

Tags: javascript, .net, bootstrap-5

I have a dropdownlistforum and I want to add a search feature. I chose to use the selectpicker library for this, but I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Constructor')` error in the console.

DroDownListFor :

```
 <div class="mb-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Repairs.urunAd, "Ürün", new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Repairs.urunID, Model.ProductsList, "Lütfen Bir Ürün Seçiniz*", new
                        {
                            @class = "selectpicker form-control repair-inputs",
                            id = "repairProductInput",
                            required = "required",
                            data_live_search = "true"
                        })
  </div>
```

Libs :

```
<link href="~/Content/css/repair.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

---

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.1/dist/bootstrap-table-locale-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/repair.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `bootstrap-select@1.13` is for Bootstrap v4. Unfortunately this module is more or less abandoned.

For a potentially more compatible option consider trying `bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3`.

Also I recommend checking out this GitHub issue: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2837.